# Sys.getenv in R

Tags: r, slurm, rscript

```
cur_dir<-"C:/Users/child/Dropbox/Proteogenomics_analysis/Proteome and Phosphoproteome Data     Normalization/Experiment_data_20230222_Metabric_multistate_analysis"
setwd(cur_dir)
library(mstate)
library(brcarepred)
```

```
id <- as.numeric(Sys.getenv("SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"))
print(id)
load("./Models/FourGroupsM.RData")
timepoints <- seq(from=0, to=20, by=0.25)
pt <- list()
newdata.DR <- newdata
newdata.DR$AGE.DR[which(newdata.DR$strata %in% seq(from=9,by=9, length=4))] <-newdata.DR$AGE.DR[which(newdata.DR$strata %in% seq(from=9,by=9, length=4))] +newdata.DR$TLastSurgery[which(newdata.DR$strata %in%seq(from=8, by=9, length=4))]pt[['DR']] <- getProbsDR(m, group=id, newdata.DR, timepoints=timepoints)`
```

I got error message.

```
pt[['DR']] <- getProbsDR(m, group=id, newdata.DR, timepoints=timepoints)
Error in group:(group + 8) : NA/NaN argument
```

I thought that this error may be resulted from

```
id <- as.numeric(Sys.getenv("SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"))
print(id)
[1] NA
```

I do not understand "Sys.getenv("SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID") script". Before running this script,
what file should I make? If possible, explain it with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is meant to be run in a Slurm [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html). Each job in the job array has a specific value defined for the `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

For instance, if the job was submitted with `--array=1-10`, there would be 10 independent jobs running, each with a distinct value for `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`, from 1 to 10.

The code retrieves that value to pass as the value of the `group` named argument to the `getProbsDR` function.

If you would like to run that script outside the context of a Slurm job array, you can defined that variable by yourself, for instance with

```
export SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID=1
```

in Linux or MacOS before invoking the R interpreted, or

```
SET SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID=1
```

in Windows.

If you are running it in RStudio, you can also try to run

```
Sys.setenv(SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID = 1)
```

before you source the code.

Obviously, you can also simply hardcode the value of `id` directly in the script.